# $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] randomly empty after htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, request-uri

When a user try to visit a file which doesn't exist, I use a .htaccess redirect to 404.php which saves the wrong URL of the missing file into database.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php [L]
```

In 404.php I'm inserting into database $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].

But for some reason in some ocassions is the REQUEST_URI empty. Even If I try to open the **same URL** over and over again then for example 1 in 10 times it will be empty.

The website using HTTPS everywhere, Debian 3.16.59-1, Apache 2.0, PHP Version 5.6.38 (don't ask me why, it's not under my control).

Where can be the problem? Can it be a bug in used technologies? Bug in browser? (newest Chrome) Or am I just missing something?

Comment: you could post your logging code, but i doubt that's the issue.

Comment: Better to use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` instead of that rule

Comment: Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? By "empty", do you mean it's literally an empty string of zero length, but is still "set"? That shouldn't be possible unless something is explicitly overwriting the PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal (in your PHP code). Are you assigning anything to this variable? My bet would be that it's a bug in the PHP code, although Apache 2.0 is "out of date". Is there anything else of significance about this server setup? Any proxy servers etc.?